# Format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss from String to date Format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datetime-format

What I am encountering is quite peculiar.

My Code:

```
   val aa = "2017-01-17 01:33:00"
    val bb = "04:33"
    val hour = bb.substring(0, bb.indexOf(":"))
    val mins = bb.substring(bb.indexOf(":") + 1, bb.length())
    val negatedmins = "-" + mins
    val ecoffsethour = hour.toLong
    val ecoffsetmins = negatedmins.toLong
    println(aa)
    val datetimeformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    val txn_post_date_hkt_date_parsed = LocalDateTime.parse(aa, datetimeformatter)
    println(txn_post_date_hkt_date_parsed)
    val minushours = txn_post_date_hkt_date_parsed.minusHours(ecoffsethour)
    println(minushours)
    val minusmins = minushours.minusMinutes(ecoffsetmins)
    println(minusmins)
    val offsetPostdateDiff = minusmins.toString().replace("T", " ")
    println(offsetPostdateDiff)
```

Output:

```
2017-01-17 01:33:00
2017-01-17T01:33
2017-01-16T21:33
2017-01-16T22:06
2017-01-16 22:06
```

In the same code I am changing only the "aa" value to ==> `2017-01-17 01:33:44`

Now the output is :

```
2017-01-17 01:33:44
2017-01-17T01:33:44
2017-01-16T21:33:44
2017-01-16T22:06:44
2017-01-16 22:06:44
```

Why is the first method not taking seconds field into consideration?

> My Requirement is : However the output should come in "yyyy-MM-dd
>   HH:mm:ss" format.

I'm quite new to Scala. Please enlighten me.

Comment: You are only using the formatter to parse not to print the date. Another problem, you are doing some time arithmetics that are already provided.

Comment: @pedrofurla : That arthimetics are as per my requirement. Hope that has got nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 2):

## Default format is ISO 8601

The java.time classes use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating strings to represent date-time value.

The standard format for a local date-time is what you are seeing with the `T` in the middle: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSSSSSSS`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
String output = ldt.toString() ;
```

> 2017-01-23T12:34:56.789

Your call `println( txn_post_date_hkt_date_parsed )` is implicitly calling the built-in `toString` method on the `LocalDateTime` object, and thereby asking for the standard ISO 8601 format with the `T`.

```
println( txn_post_date_hkt_date_parsed.toString() )
```

## Offsets

On an unrelated note, you are working too hard. The java.time classes handle offsets. I do not understand why you want an offset of such an odd number (four hours and thirty-three minutes), but so be it.

Here is your code revised, but in Java syntax.

```
String input = "2017-01-17 01:33:00" ;

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
OffsetDateTime utc = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;

ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of( "-04:33" ) ;  // Behind UTC by four hours and thirty-three minutes.
OffsetDateTime odt = utc.withOffsetSameInstant( offset ) ;
```

You can see this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/9KQjBZ). Notice how the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time) of your [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is on the previous date. Same moment in history, same point on the timeline, but viewed through two different wall-clock times ([UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), and four hours and thirty three minutes behind).

The `Z` on the end is standard ISO 8601 notation, short for `Zulu` and meaning UTC.

> input: 2017-01-17 01:33:00
>
> ldt.toString(): 2017-01-17T01:33
>
> utc.toString(): 2017-01-17T01:33Z
>
> odt.toString(): 2017-01-16T21:00-04:33

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to explicitly the format in which you want the output.

So, instead of

```
println datetime
```

You can do something like this:

```
println datetimeformat.print(datetime)
```

Good luck!

Edit: Change made to make the 2 expressions exactly equivalent

Comment: Thanks @pedrofurla.